# External screen going black every few minutes

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I've recently upgraded my home workstation by plugging an external monitor to my laptop using a vga <-> hdmi adapter (it's an older monitor that doesn't have an hdmi port).
Lately the screen has been going black for half a second or so, every 5-10 minutes. The monitor itself is not shutting off, and the internal display on the laptop keeps working when the external display goes black.  My initial guess was that it's probably a matter of the adapter overheating - but it's actually not very hot to the touch, so I'm trying to think of any other ideas as to what might be causing this.
Any clue?
Thanks!

Comment: Is it a powered adapter, and if so could the power output form the USB port be declining if the laptop battery is running low.

Comment: The adapter is not powered, but the laptop is virtually always plugged in so that's probably not what's causing the problem